# Why i am not getting image data properly or unable to send data to server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am trying to display all data which is comes from server side in my `UIViewController`.I am using `AFNetworking` in my project.I am going to sent parameter to server using `POST` method. i got response from server and i am able to display that all data like:name,email,wellness_id,mobile and image. i got image URL and i display it in `UIImageView`.

**My requirement** -  when user click on edit image button then he can select image from device and send changes to server.

**what I did:** when user click on edit image button, i can get image from device,and able to set in `UIImageView`.

**My Problem is**, why it not send any data to server?? means i am able to set image in `UIImageView` from device, but     `NSLog(@"imgdata:%@",imgdata);` this not called????
 please help me in this issue. I tried for that like this way:

```
[manager POST:Loginurl parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"Response from server  :  %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
    NSError *error;

    NSArray *temp = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseObject options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    _exceptionstr = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"exception"];
    _wellnessidstr = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"wellness_id"];
    _namestr = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"name"];
    _emailstr = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"email_id"];
    _mobilestr = [[temp objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"mobile_no"];

    _imagestr=[[temp objectAtIndex:0]valueForKey:@"profile_pic"];

    NSString *imgURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_imagestr];

    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imgURL]];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [_image setImage:[UIImage imageWithData:data]];
    });


    NSLog(@"abcde:::: %@,%@,%@,%@,%@",_namestr,_wellnessidstr,_emailstr,_mobilestr,_imagestr);

    _name.text=[NSString stringWithString:_namestr];
    NSLog(@"%@",_name.text);


    _mobile.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",_mobilestr];

    _email.text=[NSString stringWithString:_emailstr];
    NSLog(@"%@",_email.text);

    _wellness_id.text=[NSString stringWithString:_wellnessidstr];
    NSLog(@"%@",_wellness_id.text);
```

for pick up image from device and send changes to server:

```
- (IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender {
    UIImagePickerController *imagePickerController = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

    imagePickerController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationCurrentContext;

    imagePickerController.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;

    imagePickerController.delegate = self;

    [self presentViewController:imagePickerController animated:YES completion:nil];
}



- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    UIImage *imageimg = [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];

    [_image setImage:imageimg];

    NSData *imgdata = UIImagePNGRepresentation(_image.image);

    NSLog(@"imgdata:%@",imgdata);

    AppDelegate *del = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];


    NSString *Loginurl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/EditProfiles/Pic",del.Root_URL];

    NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString *t = [prefs stringForKey:@"token"];
    NSLog(@"%@",t);


    NSDictionary *params = @{@"token":t,

                             @"profile_pic":imgdata

                             };

    //here we can see parameters which is sent to server


    NSLog(@"Sent parameter to edit image server : %@",params);



    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];

    manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializerWithReadingOptions:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments];


    manager.responseSerializer = [AFHTTPResponseSerializer serializer];


    AFSecurityPolicy* policy = [AFSecurityPolicy policyWithPinningMode:AFSSLPinningModeCertificate];

    [policy setValidatesDomainName:NO];

    [policy setAllowInvalidCertificates:YES];


    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json", @"text/json", @"text/javascript",@"text/html", nil];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/html",nil];

    manager.responseSerializer.acceptableContentTypes = [NSSet setWithObjects:@"application/json",@"text/plain",nil];



    [manager POST:Loginurl parameters:params progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionTask *task, id responseObject) {


        // Here we can see response which is coming from server

        NSLog(@"Response from server  :  %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
```

Comment: `my problem is, why it not send any data to server??` clarify this please.

Comment: means in - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info --------
 upto this [_image setImage:imageimg]; it works, it display image in UIImageView, but     NSLog(@"imgdata:%@",imgdata);
is not called.... @vaibhav

Comment: check my ans and let me know your feedback.

Comment: Do you want to post your image as NSData to server?

Comment: yes... @DipankarDas

Comment: You should encode this image as base64string & then post it to server.

Comment: can you please post your answer @DipankarDas sir..? it helps me alot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just configure your `UIImagePickerController` inside buttons action then try.

```
- (IBAction)changeImage:(id)sender {

   UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
   picker.delegate = self;
   picker.allowsEditing = YES;
   picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
   [self presentViewController:picker animated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

You can get the image data using `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` delegate method below:

```
- (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {

   UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
   NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage)];
   NSLog(@"imgdata:%@",imageData);

   self.yourImageView.image = chosenImage;
   [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

Comment: Something better from previous.....now 2 issues i occur---> 1]now it print like imgdata:<>  2] when i select image it just print imgdata:<>, but why image is not set in UIImageView ???

Comment: @SurajSukale then you need to set image to imageView, check updated ans.

Comment: Yes, i tried that already like     [_image setImage:chosenImage];
this way, and now by using this also   self.yourImageView.image = chosenImage;
but image is not displayed in UIImageView.

Comment: imageView's connected outlet is all ok sir, because it works me previously,just did't get imagedata , now i got that but image is not display in UIImageView as well as imagedata is only <> ....??

Comment: actually problem is in your `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method, you are doing many more stuff inside this method just remove other code from inside and create diff modules to handle other task.

Comment: just use `didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo` method what i have suggested and remove other code form then try sure helps.

Comment: - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:(NSDictionary *)info {
    
    UIImage *chosenImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerEditedImage];
    NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(chosenImage)];
    NSLog(@"imgdata:%@",imageData);
    [_image setImage:chosenImage];
   // self.image.image = chosenImage;
    [picker dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
 I only doing this sir, still image is not display in UIImageView.

Comment: is any need to use [info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage]; this sir???

Comment: whats the `_image` can you show your imageView's outlet?, call vaibhav please.

Comment: no `[info valueForKey:UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage];`

Comment: @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *image;
is my image outlet

Comment: try changing your imageView's name because image only may overrides existing class functionality. Reconnect your outlet then please.

Comment: unfortunately issue will be same @Vaibhav.. didn't get, where i'm going in wrong way?

Comment: I observed one thing @vaibhav, when i change my image it doesn't display changed as well as previous image...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131704/discussion-between-vaibhav-and-suraj-sukale).